How to get an object by max value in Django ORM
I'm searching for a better way to do this: i need to get an object with the highest value in a model.
The value isn't stored in a field, instead it is a number of objects from related(secondary) model (ManyToOne relations, ForeignKey)
I've tried this:
from django.db.models import *

annotatedPM = PrimaryModel.objects.annotate(Count('secondarymodel'))
max_value = annotatedPM.aggregate(Max('secondarymodel__count'))['secondarymodel__count__max']
annotatedPM.get(secondarymodel__count=max_value)
>>> <PrimaryModel: object>

This variant works well, but i'm wondering, is there any better way to do this?

Just order the items by the annotations:
from django.db.models import Count

annotatedPM = PrimaryModel.objects.annotate(Count('secondarymodel')).order_by(
    '-secondarymodel__count'
).first()
or even shorter with .latest(…) [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import Count

annotatedPM = PrimaryModel.objects.annotate(Count('secondarymodel')).latest(
    'secondarymodel__count'
)
this will raise an error if there is no PrimaryModel record in the entire table.

Somehow i didn't think at all about the fact that i can access the annotation with .order_by()
Thanks a lot!
